# nested ngrepeat, get the index in the nested array

Tags: angularjs

can you help me with the index in the nested ng-repeat ? I can't find the right way to take the first 8 element of prodata, then the 8 following elements, then the 8 following elements...etc.

```
<ion-slide-box show-pager="true" does-continue="true" on-slide-changed="slideHasChanged($index)">
        <ion-slide ng-repeat="s in [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]">
            <ul>
                <li ng-repeat="item in prodata | limitTo:8*s+8:8*s+0">
                {{s}}
                    <a class="suggestPro" href="#">
                        <span><img ng-src="img/boards/{{item.imageName}}" /></span>
                        <p class="flex-caption"> {{item.model}} - {{item.name}}</p>
                    </a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </ion-slide>
    </ion-slide-box>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check your angular version. The ability to specify the begin argument has been added to 1.4 version of angular :

Extract from [angular's change log](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#features-11) :

limitTo: extend the filter to take a beginning index argument (aaae3cc4, #5355, #10899)

Your code wil be :

```
<li ng-repeat="item in prodata | limitTo:8:8*s">
```

Comment: I would not recommend using filers for this problem because of the performance concerns. FYI, filters are executed on each digest which would make the digest cycle really slow in cases of big arrays.

Answer (score 0):

The best way IMO would be to reformat the initial array to make it suitable for usage with ng-repeat. Example:

```
var getSplittedArray = function (array, numberOfElements) {
    var newArray = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i += 1) {
        if (i % numberOfElements === 0) {
            newArray.push([]);
        }
        newArray[newArray.length - 1].push(array[i]);
    }
    return newArray;
}

// Example: var realArray = someService.get();
$scope.splittedArray = getSplittedArray(realArray, 8);
```

Example usage in the view:

```
<ion-slide-box show-pager="true" does-continue="true" on-slide-changed="slideHasChanged($index)">
    <ion-slide ng-repeat="set in splittedArray">
        <ul>
            <li ng-repeat="item in set">
            {{s}}
                <a class="suggestPro" href="#">
                    <span><img ng-src="img/boards/{{item.imageName}}" /></span>
                    <p class="flex-caption"> {{item.model}} - {{item.name}}</p>
                </a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </ion-slide>
</ion-slide-box>
```